# Download file from SVN Repository in C#.net

Tags: asp.net, tortoisesvn, download

How can I download file from SVN repository from my web application in C#.net?
I want to download file programatically. When button is clicked, it should download file from URL given in TextBox.

Answer (score 6):

First off, you should be able to access (read-only) the file directly on the repository without the need for an SVN client (though you may need authentication). In that case, it's just like downloading any file from any URL:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    // In case you need authentication...
    // client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    client.DownloadFile(fileUrl, localDestinationPath);
}
```

However, like Vinayak said, SharpSvn is not a bad way to go-- it's pretty good for handling SVN interactions. So if using the standard WebClient doesn't work, you can do the following in SharpSvn to get the file stream:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    client.Write(SvnTarget.FromUri(svnFilePath), stream);
}
return stream;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: WebClient worked fine for me... just needed to set the credentials

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

I've also found another [SharpSvn Tutorial](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/docs/walkthrough.htm) which i hope u'll find helpful. It has everything from Introduction to SVN Operations(checkout,commit, etc)

Also,

1. Read about [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) and check out [this blog](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/sharpsvn-brings)
2. there are few related examples for [Checkout, update, commit in c#](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectProcess?documentContainer=c4__Samples&view)
3. The [source code](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=207&expandFolder=207&folderID=207) contains an example project as well